# Are there ways to do something like "case when value in table" in AS400 DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Looking for a way to do something like

```
with T(A) as (values (1), (2), (439), (438), (13000023) ),
    TT(B) as (values (2), (438))
select
    A,
    (CASE 
        WHEN (A IN (select B from tt) ) THEN 0
        ELSE A 
        END) AS CODE 
    from T
```

(For information, the above doesn't work, and I get Error: [SQL0115] Opérateur de comparaison IN incorrect. SQLState:  42601 ErrorCode: -115

Any suggestion is welcome. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a left join will help you here:

```
with T(A) as (values (1), (2), (439), (438), (13000023) ),
    TT(B) as (values (2), (438))
select case
       when B is NULL then A
       else 0
       end
from T
left join TT
    on A = B;
```

Note that you may have to modify this if the keys are not unique.

Comment: I should have thought of this one... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select A,
      (CASE WHEN A IN (select B from tt) THEN 0
            ELSE A 
        END) AS CODE 
from T
```

An alias is not appropriate after the `IN`.

Comment: Tried this also, with the same error message. But thanks for the tip, I'll drop the alias in my question.